Poincaré Extension of Mobius transformation
Suppose $\phi\in GM(\hat{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}})$, Group of Möbius transformation,  and that $\phi$ leaves $H^{n+1}$ invariant.  Show that $\phi$ is the Poincaré extension of some $\psi \in GM(\hat{\mathbb{R}^n}).$
This question is from the book "The Geometry of Discrete Groups "by Alan F. Beardon, section 3.3.
1)If $\phi$ is a reflection in the plane $p(\tilde{a},t)$ where $\tilde{a}=(a_1,a_2,..,a_n,0)$ then $\phi$ satisfy all the conditions in the hypothesis and $\phi$ is the extension of reflection in $p(a,t)$, where $a=(a_1,..,a_n)$.
2)Any two reflections are conjugate in $GM(\hat{\mathbb {R}^{n+1}})$.
I think we need to use these two facts for general Möbius transformation.
